# how to hide and show image in listview in android?

Tags: java, android

I have one list in which I have one image view .I need to show that image only when my one variable is true .Actually I make a custom adapter in which I have one variable "serviceAlertPresent" .If it is true  I need to show image elese I don't want to show image on row.How I Will acheive this

Here is my code of each row .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
android:padding="5dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_platform"
      android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"

        android:text="Ptf."
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />



    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_schDepart"
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/item_platform"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/item_platform"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/item_platform"
        android:text="dpt"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_arrival"
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/item_schDepart"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/item_schDepart"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/item_expectdepart"
        android:text="Arr."
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_expectdepart"
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/item_schDepart"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/item_platform"
        android:text="Expert"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_expertarrival"
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/item_expectdepart"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/item_expectdepart"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/item_arrival"
        android:text="exprt Arrival"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_stationName"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/item_arrival"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/item_arrival"
        android:layout_marginLeft="17dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/item_expertarrival"
        android:text="Des."
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/alertStatus"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/item_stationName"
     android:src="@drawable/alert_icon" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

here is custom adapter

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    ArrayList<deparaturedaseboarddto> deparaturedaseboarddto;
    private Context context;
    public CustomListAdapter( Context context, ArrayList<deparaturedaseboarddto> deparaturedaseboarddto){
        this.deparaturedaseboarddto=deparaturedaseboarddto;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return deparaturedaseboarddto.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return deparaturedaseboarddto.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         View v = convertView;
            if (v == null) {
                LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                v = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_listitem, null);
            }

            final TextView platFormName = (TextView) v
                    .findViewById(R.id.item_platform);

            final TextView schDepart = (TextView) v
                    .findViewById(R.id.item_schDepart);
            final TextView expDepart = (TextView) v
                    .findViewById(R.id.item_expectdepart);
            final TextView arrival = (TextView) v
                    .findViewById(R.id.item_arrival);
            final TextView exparrival = (TextView) v
                    .findViewById(R.id.item_expertarrival);
            final TextView stationName = (TextView) v
                    .findViewById(R.id.item_stationName);

            final String platformValue = deparaturedaseboarddto.get(position).getPlatformNo();
            final String schDepartValue= deparaturedaseboarddto.get(position).getSchDepart();
            final String schExpectValue= deparaturedaseboarddto.get(position).getExpDepart();
            final String arrivalValue= deparaturedaseboarddto.get(position).getDestSchArrival();
            final String exparrivalValue= deparaturedaseboarddto.get(position).getDestSchArrival();
           String stationNameValue= deparaturedaseboarddto.get(position).getDestinationStation().getStationName();

            platFormName.setText(platformValue);

            schDepart.setText(schDepartValue);
            expDepart.setText(schExpectValue);
            arrival.setText(arrivalValue);
            exparrival.setText(exparrivalValue);
            stationName.setText(stationNameValue);
            return v;
    }

    public void referhList( ArrayList<deparaturedaseboarddto> deparaturedaseboarddto){
        this.deparaturedaseboarddto=deparaturedaseboarddto;

        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}
```

I am asking this image view

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/alertStatus"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/item_stationName"
     android:src="@drawable/alert_icon" />
```

I need to show this when **"serviceAlertPresent"** .I will get value like that **deparaturedaseboarddto.get(position).isServiceAlertPresent()**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the adapter get the imageView and set the visibilite to INVISIBLE or VISIBLE.

```
final ImageView alertStatus = (ImageView) v
                    .findViewById(R.id.alertStatus);

if (condition){
     alertStatus.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
else{
     alertStatus.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
```

And when the condition change, you should call notifyDataSetChanged() of your adapter.

Hope it helps you!

Answer (score 1):

You can check boolean values of serviceAlertPresent inside `getView()` method itself.

If it's true then use `mImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)` else remove the presence of it by using `mImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE)`.

**Note:** When you use GONE, it will be invisible and at the same time it will not take any space, where as when you use INVISIBLE it will be invisible and will take space in layout.

Comment: When using View.Gone. The element is removed complete from view. Android recalculates the view. Use View.INVISIBLE. To hide

Comment: @marcel thanks for the pointer. Updated answer with details which could help even novice developers too :-)

Answer (score 0):

In `ImageView`, set `android:setVisiblity="gone";` by default.

show that image only when your variable is true.

like,

```
imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: setVisibility accepts `int` value which is VISIBLE, INVISIBLE or GONE constant!

Answer (score -1):

```
 final ImageView alertStatus= (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.alertStatus);
v.alertStatus.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```